# why ckeditor send null image to upload file

Tags: asp.net-core, upload, ckeditor, ckeditor4

The following codes are the codes I wrote to use the ckeditor in asp core5 ,but  When I upload the image, it sends null file to UploadFile function in controlller
Why?

I hope you can help me because I really need it

> ```
> Controller:
>         [HttpPost]
>         [AllowAnonymous]
>         public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile File)
>         {
>
>             return Json(_postService.UploadFile(File));
>
>         }
>
> view:
> <scripts>
>         CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
>
>             filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'Uploads',
>          
>             filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/Blog/UploadFile',
>
> }
> </scripts>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile File)` code used for choosing local image file without using ckeditor. When using ckeditor4, we can submit all the properities in model.

[image]

For more details, you can check the blog and the repo.

[Blog: Integrate CK Editor to ASP .NET Core MVC Web Application](https://enlear.academy/integrate-ck-editor-to-asp-net-core-mvc-web-application-239b2cd18556)

[Repo: CKEditor-MSQL-DB](https://github.com/aLLUPS/CKEditor-MSSQL-DB)